# Closure of numeric relations on integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am given the example that the reflexive closure of the relation *less* on integers r(*less*) is *lessOrEqual*. Furthermore, closures can yield all possible pairs; e.g. *r(notEqual*) = $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

I want to know from there, how to describe the following closures on the integers:

a) *s(less)*

b) *t(less)*

c) *s(notEqual)*

d) *t(notEqual)*

But I am confused by the example provided what exactly is being described?

Comment: I don't understand  $\{(a,b)| a< b\} \cup \{(a,b)|a = b\} = \{(a,b)| a \le b\}\not \equiv \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$. and that can *not* yield all pairs.  It can not, for example, yield $(29,13)$ and it can not yield *any* $(a,b)$ where $a > b$.

Comment: I believe I had it syntactically wrong. Meant to say, that the closure yields of all possible pairs, e.g. $*r(notEqual)* = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see.

If $foobar = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z| a \ foobar \ b\}$ then

the *kumquatat*ive closure of $foobar$ is $k(foobar)=\{(a,b)|a \ foobar\ b\}$ but $foobar$ is extended so that that set is now *kumquatat*ive.

So

A) $foobar$ = $less$ so

$foobar = \{(a,b)| a< b\}\subset \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

1) $kumquat$ive means reflexive.

So $r(less) = \{(a,b)|a < b\} \cup \{(c,c)\} = $

$\{(a,b)|a < b\} \cup \{(a,b)| a= b\} =$

$\{(a,b)|a< b$ or $a=b\} = \{(a,b)|a\le b\} = lessOrEqual$.

2) symmetric

$s(less) = \{(a,b)|a < b\} \cup \{(b,a)| a < b\}=$

$\{(a,b)|a< b$ or $b > a\} = \{(a,b)|a\ne b\} = notEqual$

3) transitive

$\{(a,b)|a< b\} \cup \{(a,c)|\exists b, a<b; b < c\}$

okay.... $less$ was transitive in the first place so the closure is itself.

Or other words.  If $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$ so $\{(a,c)|\exists b, a<b; b < c\} \subset \{(a,b)|a < b\}=lessThan$ so

$\{(a,b)|a< b\} \cup \{(a,c)|\exists b, a<b; b < c\}= \{(a,b)|a < b\}=lessThan$

B) $notEqual$.

1) reflexive:

$r(notEqual)= \{(a,b)|a \ne b\} \cup \{(c,c)\}=$

$\{(a,b)|a \ne b\}\cup \{(a,b)|a=b\}=$

$\{(a,b)|a \ne b$ OR $a= b\} =$

$\{(a,b)|a$ and $b$ do whatever they freakin' want$\} = $

$\{(a,b)|a\in \mathbb Z, b\in \mathbb Z\}= \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

2) symmetric

$s(notEqual) = \{(a,b)|a\ne b\} \cup \{(b,a)| a\ne b\}=$

$\{(a,b)|a\ne b$ or $b\ne a\} = \{(a,b)|a \ne b\}=$

$notEqual$

Which ... as $notEqual$ is symmetric, its closure must be itself.

3) transitive

$t(notEqual) =$

$\{(a,b)| a \ne b\} \cup \{(a,c)|\exists b; a\ne b, b\ne c\}$.

Okay... reality check.  If $a$ is $a$ and $c$ is $c$ we can always find a $b$ so that $a \ne b$ and $b \ne c$.  For instance $b = \max (a,c)+1$.  Then $b > \max (a,c) \le a,c$ so $b\ne a,c$.

So $\{a,c)|\exists b; a\ne b, b\ne c\} = \{(a,c)\} = \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanations. They are rather helpful on something I was completely lost in thinking of.